# Scala from_json function is throwing error when i use options

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my code:

```
val opts = Map("allowUnquotedFieldNames" -> "true")
    
val df_withSchema = df.withColumn("Data", from_json(col("Item.Data.S"),schema, opts))
```

Below is the error:

```
(<console>:198: error: overloaded method value from_json with alternatives:
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,options: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: String,options: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: String,options: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType,options: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType,options: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType,options: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType,options: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType, scala.collection.Map[String,String])
           val df_withSchema = df.withColumn("Data", from_json(col("Item.Data.S"),schema, opts))
                                                     ^
,0,1388)
```

Can someone please help me understand why this code is throwing error and how to fix this?

**Background:**

Data element is a Nested JSON stored as string. So i have defined a schema for Data element and converting it as JSON using from_JSON. Also, the fields names inside Data are under quotes so i am trying to use options here(*Map("allowUnquotedFieldNames" -> "true")*)

Comment: What kind of `Map` is in your code?

Comment: @mazaneicha
I referred to this syntax and used Map: [from_json function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType-scala.collection.immutable.Map-)

Comment: It was a hint (a rhetorical question) :)) The doc in your link also clearly shows the Map type -- immutable -- that should be used, as @Dima said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, and you have `scala.collection.Map` ...

I know, one would naively expect to be able to use just any kind of a map with the code that promises not to mutate it, but it does't work like that. It is actually the other way around: `immutable.Map` is a subclass of `Map`.

Try doing `opts.toMap`, that should fix it.